Swap domain on outbound emails
I am using MS365 and would like to have the domain for all outbound email sent to a particular domain swapped to another domain. I believe this would be achieved with a outbound connector in O365.
For example if the destination domain is "domain123.com" then change it to "domain456.com"
An email sent to username@domain123.com would be sent to username@domain456.com
Is this possible?
